# How to add 3 to the second element of my array named list?

Tags: c

int list[8] = { 7, 9, 11, 0, 1, 3, 4, 99 };

```
scan f_s("%d", &list[1]);

list[1] + 3;
```

I tried these and it's not working

Comment: list[1] = list[1] + 3;

Comment: `list[1] += 3;`

Answer (score 0):

you need to assignt the value back to list[i], so itc it would be something like.

```
list[1] = list[1] + 3;
```